# Problemas na automação de envio de mensagens no WhatsApp através da biblioteca selenium pelo Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, chatbot

Estou com um projeto de envio automático de mensagens via WhatsApp que consiste em mandar mensagens providas de caracteres especiais (emojis e outros símbolos) guardados em arquivos .txt, no entanto, sempre que uso o seguinte código:

```
Trava = open('c:/Users/Marco Neto/Desktop/ataquepalhaco.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

(...)

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe')
```

Ele dá o seguinte erro:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

Já procurei pesquisar sobre, contudo, a única solução que achei em relação a esse problema foi de mudar de webdriver e, ao invés de usar o do Chrome, usar o do Firefox. Tentei por meio do código a seguir mas que infelizmente também deu errado:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver.exe')
```

Erro do código acima:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Resumindo, gostaria de uma alternativa ou resolução para os códigos para que eu possa inserir caracteres especiais em um arquivo .txt e mandá-lo por WhatsApp pelo selenium.

Comment: Fica muito difícil reproduzir o erro com as informações que você passou. Não é mais fácil vc usar strings chaves no seu txt e fazer o selenium procurar pelo item na aba dos emoticons?

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível enviar emojis utilizando o Chrome no momento, devido a um [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269). Você deve usar o firefox.

Quanto ao erro na inicialização do Firefox, existem várias possibilidades:

- O firefox não está instalado no seu sistema, ou não está no PATH
- Sistema em 64 bits, mas GeckDriver/Firefox em 32 bits; ou vice-e-versa
- No Windows, os [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistribuível para Visual Studio 2015, 2017 e 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) não estão instalados - necessário para o GeckoDriver
- GeckoDriver para Firefox versão 46 ou anterior deve ser iniciado da seguinte forma em versões modernas do Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('http://google.com/')
browser.quit()
```

Além disso, o parâmetro `executable_path` de `webdriver.Firefox` espera um caminho completo, mas você passou um relativo. Experimente substituir './geckodriver.exe' pelo endereço completo de onde está este executável.

Answer (score 0):

Já tive em mãos um projeto desta caracteristica.

Utilizei a api do whatsApp para automatizar o envios de textos e emojis,  envio de fotos e vídeos foi muuuuito loooongo o tempo codando mas funcionou bem.

Para enviar mensagem usando o pc, inicialmente tem que passar pelo QR Code.
Da para burlar esse mecanismo usando mv.

Infelizmente na sua dúvida não passou o código,apenas um parte mas irei mostrar um exemplo simples do meu github.

Quando iniciado ira pedir autentificação pelo celular, sera redirecionado a pagina de mensagem e enviara texto para cada numero indicado.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import schedule
 
class Whatsapp:

    def driver(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/..') # driver google
        return driver

    def mensagem_whatsapp(self, mensagem, numeros_celulares):

       driver_extensao = Whatsapp().driver()
        driver_extensao.get(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={numeros_celulares}&source=&data=#") # api web
        print("Autentificaçao[Web, Desktop] ")
        driver_extensao.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        campo = driver_extensao.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
        print("Envio : ", campo.send_keys(mensagem))
        campo.send_keys("\n")


def robo():
    pessoas = [0010101] # lista de numeros
    mensagemE = "Ola, estao" # frase, pode interagir com teu txt

    enviarAgora = Whatsapp()
    for possomandar in pessoas:
        enviarAgora.mensagem_whatsapp(mensagem=mensagemE, numeros_celulares=pessoas)
```

#só iniciar com main com o função robô

[fonte whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/?lang=pt_br)